# Cox regression with visreg2d

Tags: visualization, survival-analysis

I have two continous covariates and survival time/event.

I am trying to visualize the Hazards of mortality by the 2 covariates simultaneously.

This is my `R` code:

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(time, death==1) ~ pspline(A)+pspline(B), data=data)

visreg2d(fit, "A", "B")
```

I get this result image: [image: output]

As you can see, the Z axis is giving me `log(hazards)` which is hard to interpret. Is there a way to get the Hazards (i.e. `e^(log Hazard)`)?

Thanks